# How to capture authorized PayPal payment automatically in paypal standard?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to implement paypal authorization and capture payment automatically. I have used paypal standard account. I have send payment request with authorization parameter.

```
<form:form commandName="paymentForm" id="paymentForm" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="paypal">           
    <form:input path="cmd" id="cmd" name="cmd" type="hidden" />
    <form:input path="business" id="business" name="business" type="hidden" />
    <form:input path="password" id="password" name="password" type="hidden" />
    <form:input path="custom" id="custom"  name="custom" type="hidden" />
    <form:input path="item_name" id="item_name" name="item_name" type="hidden" />       
    <form:input path="amount"  id="amount" name="amount" type="hidden" />
    <form:input path="currencyCode" type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
    <form:input path="rm"  id="rm" name="rm" type="hidden" />
    <%-- <form:input path="returnUrl"  id="return" name="return" type="hidden" /> --%>      
    <form:input type="hidden" name="return" value="${paymentForm.returnUrl}" />
    <form:input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" path="cancel_return" />
    <form:input type="hidden" name="cert_id" path="certId" />
    <form:input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" path="authorization">
</form:form>
```

Now I want to capture the payment by using sending Http request to paypal with transaction Id/ authorization Id. How can I do this?

Thanks In Advance

K.Lakshmi Priya

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make an API call to the `DoCapture` [API call](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoCapture_API_Operation_NVP/).
If you haven't used PayPal's API calls before, I suggest reading the [Getting Started guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/gs_PayPalAPIs/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

The following java code make Capture the authorized payment by using DoCapture API Call

```
import com.paypal.sdk.core.nvp.NVPDecoder;
import com.paypal.sdk.core.nvp.NVPEncoder;
import com.paypal.sdk.exceptions.PayPalException;
import com.paypal.sdk.profiles.APIProfile;
import com.paypal.sdk.profiles.ProfileFactory;
import com.paypal.sdk.services.NVPCallerServices;

public class DoCapture {     
   public static final String DO_CAPTURE_METHOD = "DoCapture";

public static void main(String[] args) throws PayPalException {

    APIProfile profile;
    profile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile();
        profile.setAPIUsername("API User Name");
        profile.setAPIPassword("PWD");
        profile.setSignature("API Signature");
       // profile.setEnvironment("sandbox");
       // profile.setSubject("");
       // profile.setTimeout(timeout);

    NVPEncoder encoder = new NVPEncoder();
NVPDecoder decoder = new NVPDecoder();

    NVPCallerServices caller = new NVPCallerServices();
    caller.setAPIProfile(profile);

    encoder.add("METHOD", DO_CAPTURE_METHOD);
    encoder.add("AUTHORIZATIONID", "8PR03910DP1572333");
    encoder.add("COMPLETETYPE", "Complete");
    encoder.add("AMT", "100");
    encoder.add("CURRENCYCODE", "EUR");

    String NVPRequest = encoder.encode();
    String NVPResponse = caller.call(NVPRequest);
    decoder.decode(NVPResponse);

    System.out.println("PayPal Response :: "+NVPResponse);
}
}
```

For more detail refer https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoCapture_API_Operation_NVP/

Answer (score 0):

In c# you can capture payment using following code.

```
public ActionResult CaptureAuthorization()
    {
        APIContext apiContext = Configuration.GetAPIContext();
        try
        {
            Authorization authorization = Authorization.Get(apiContext, "6SY29185GS4409204");//Provide Payment Id returned after authorizing payment.
            Capture capture = new Capture();
            Amount captureAmount = new Amount();
            captureAmount.currency = "USD";
            captureAmount.total = "7";
            capture.amount = captureAmount;

            Capture responseCap = authorization.Capture(apiContext, capture);//Capture Payment

            if (responseCap.state.ToLower() != "completed")
            {
                return View("Failure");
            }

            return View("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View("Failure");
        }
    }
```